# Gradle cannot build JAR with dependecies for Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, dockerfile

I have a `Spring` `MVC` application that I want to add to `Docker`. I created the `image`, configured `Docker`, but the application in `Docker` does not want to start. How can I fix the problem?

I tried different ways to fix this error, for example, I added the following code to `gradle.build`:

```java
dependencies {
extraLibs group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna-platform', version: '4.2.2'
// ... dependencies ...
configurations.compile.extendsFrom(configurations.extraLibs)
}
```

But it didn't work.

GRADLE:

```java
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

//configurations {
    // configuration that holds jars to include in the jar
 //   extraLibs
//}

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
//


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": 'ru.coffeetearea.CoffeeTeArea'
    }
}

ext {
    javaMainClass = "ru.coffeetearea.CoffeeTeArea"
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

dependencies {
//    extraLibs group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna-platform', version: '4.2.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.11'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    // Thymeleaf
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    // Swagger UI
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
    // Swagger 2
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.14'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-core
    compile group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: '6.5.1'
    // MapStruct
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.1.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.1.Final'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-jpamodelgen
    annotationProcessor('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:6.0.0.Alpha5')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.3.2.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt
    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.4.0-b180830.0359'
    // JUnit
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.2')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.1.0'
//    configurations.compile.extendsFrom(configurations.extraLibs)
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

DOCKERFILE:

```java
FROM openjdk:11
ADD build/libs/Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 5432
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Manifest.MF:

```java
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: ru.coffeetearea.CoffeeTeArea
```

ERRORS:

```java
C:\Users\vartanyan\IdeaProjects\Coffeetearea>docker run -p 5432:5432 coffeetearea
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at ru.coffeetearea.CoffeeTeArea.main(CoffeeTeArea.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot, but in your build are totally ignoring it and working around it. Don't. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-container-images-docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Spring Boot in your application and in your build you are trying very hard to **not** use it. In short don't, use the Spring Boot Gradle plugin to build a proper jar

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

dependencies {
//    extraLibs group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna-platform', version: '4.2.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: 
'3.11'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    // Swagger UI
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
    // Swagger 2
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql
    implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-core
    implementation group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core'
    // MapStruct
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.1.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.1.Final'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-jpamodelgen
    annotationProcessor('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:6.0.0.Alpha5')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt
    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.4.0-b180830.0359'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

Now when you do `./gradlew build` it will generate a proper Spring Boot jar that you can run on the command-line. This jar you can also use in your docker images.

As of Spring Boot 2.3 it is possible to let Spring Boot create the image as well using [build packs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-container-images-buildpacks) or [regular docker](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-container-images-docker).

When using a build pack, the above `build.gradle` is enough to create an image. Just run `./gradlew bootBuildImage`, it will then use build packs to generate an image.